# Algoritmo de suma de matrices cuadradas - Divide y venceras

Tags: c++

Estoy teniendo problemas para poder implementar un algoritmo que devuelva como resultado la suma de dos matrices cuadradas a través del método divide y vencerás.

```
void suma_matriz(int matriz1[MAX][MAX], matriz2[MAX][MAX]) 
{ 

 int i = 0; 
 int j = 0; 
 int aux[MAX][MAX]; 
 if (i < MAX) { 
   aux[j][i] = matriz[i][j]; 
   i++; 
 } 
 else if (j < MAX) { 
   aux[j][i] = matriz[i][j]; 
   j++; 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Hola @sobrius, te invitamos a realizar el [recorrido o tour de la comunidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Además, deberías de leer [¿cómo elaborar una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Y por ultimo, te recomiendo que utilices la barra de herramientas para identar y darle formato a tu código con el signo *{ }* , podrás ver mas información en el tour que te he dejado.

Answer (score 2):

Es raro que tengas problemas con el algoritmo Divide y Vencerás (DyV) porque ni siquiera usas dicho algoritmo. [Según Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_divide_y_vencer%C3%A1s):

### Divide y Vencerás.

> En las [ciencias de la computación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciencias_de_la_computaci%C3%B3n), el término **divide y vencerás (DYV)** hace referencia a uno de los más importantes paradigmas de diseño [algorítmico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo). El método está basado en la resolución [recursiva](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividad) de un problema dividiéndolo en dos o más subproblemas de igual tipo o similar. El proceso continúa hasta que éstos llegan a ser lo suficientemente sencillos como para que se resuelvan directamente. Al final, las soluciones a cada uno de los subproblemas se combinan para dar una solución al problema original.

Tu código ni siquiera hace uso de la recursión, así que difícilmente puede ser un DyV. Por otro lado, un algoritmo DyV para sumar matrices no parece tener sentido al ser una operación de suma por cada componente de cada coordenada:

C<sub>mn</sub> = A<sub>mn</sub> + B<sub>mn</sub>

### Problemas.

En vista de tu código (que no usa DyV) y del poco sentido que tiene el DyV en este contexto, creo que en realidad no pretendes usar DyV para sumar matrices. De ser así, tu código tiene varios problemas que deberías resolver.

#### Pasas las matrices por copia.

Tu función `suma_matriz` está recibiendo dos matrices de tamaño MAX × MAX mediante copia, esto puede ser un problema de rendimiento si las matrices son grandes, mejor pasa las matrices por referencia:

```
void suma_matriz(const int (&matriz1)[MAX][MAX], const (&matriz2)[MAX][MAX])
```

Dado que tampoco vas a modificar las matrices de entrada, deberá ser referencia constante.

#### El tamaño de las matrices está fijado.

Tu función `suma_matriz` sólo puede recibir matrices de tamaño MAX × MAX, esto es muy poco flexible, mejor usa una plantilla:

```
template <std::size_t MAX>
void suma_matriz(const int (&matriz1)[MAX][MAX], const (&matriz2)[MAX][MAX])
```

De esta manera, el compilador deducirá el tamaño de las matrices sin necesidad de crear una constante `MAX`.

#### No sumas nada.

Tu función `suma_matriz` debería de alguna manera devolver la suma entre `matriz1` y `matriz2`, pero no devuelves nada. Dado que C++ no permite devolver matrices, la manera de devolver una suma sería facilitando un parámetro por referencia no constante:

```
template <std::size_t MAX>
void suma_matriz(const int (&matriz1)[MAX][MAX], const (&matriz2)[MAX][MAX],
    (&resultado)[MAX][MAX])
```

En `resultado` se guardaría la suma de `matriz1` y `matriz2`.

#### No sumas nada, segunda parte.

En tu código:

```
if (i < MAX) { 
  aux[j][i] = matriz[i][j]; 
  i++; 
} 
else if (j < MAX) { 
  aux[j][i] = matriz[i][j]; 
  j++; 
}
```

Ni siquiera tienes una suma, por no tener no tienes ni un bucle para recorrer los campos de la matriz: seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
for (int i = 0; i != MAX; ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j != MAX; ++j)
        resultado[i][j] = matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j];
```

### Propuesta.

Con estas correcciones tu código podría quedar así:

```
template <std::size_t MAX>
void suma_matriz(const int (&matriz1)[MAX][MAX], const (&matriz2)[MAX][MAX],
    (&resultado)[MAX][MAX])
{
    for (int i = 0; i != MAX; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j != MAX; ++j)
            resultado[i][j] = matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j];
}
```